# Calling a constructor within another constructor using 'this' as an argument

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
 public Insight3DPluginControl(Insight3DPlugin plugin, MapViewModel viewModel)
            : base(plugin)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RXMouse = new RXMapMouse(this);
            eob_tool = new EOBTool(RXMouse);
         }
```

and I've been trying to wrap my head around the use of 'this' in new RXMapMouse() that is being called by 'this's constructor. I'm trying to understand the reason for doing this and what the design pattern would be called.

I understand that the object before being passed to RXMapMouse() is already initialized, but does that mean by changing the current Insight3DPluginControl object when we assign the RXMouse field, will then change the one inside of RXMapMouse()?

Comment: This is actually rather bad code: it's passing an instance to RXMapMouse that isn't fully initialized yet. That's just asking for problems, really.

Comment: How do you mean not yet fully initialized? Do you mean the first instance is initialized in the RXMapMouse constructor, then redefined in the Insight3DPlugin control assignment? Or do you mean its only initialized up until the RXMapMouse constructor

Comment: There's no initialization of `Insight3DPluginControl` going on in `RxMapMouse`, it's only assignment. Jeroen was referring to the fact that `Insight3DPluginControl` did not even finish going through its constructor (`eob_tool` creation) and already it was sending itself.

Answer (score 0):

The "this" keyword is a "variable" representing the current object.

Maybe this ( :D ) will let you undestand it better:

```
 public Insight3DPluginControl(Insight3DPlugin plugin, MapViewModel viewModel)
    : base(plugin)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Insight3DPluginControl theControl = this;

        RXMouse = new RXMapMouse(theControl);
        eob_tool = new EOBTool(RXMouse);
     }
```

So, basically the "RXMapMouse" needs an instance of an "Insight3DPluginControl" int it's constructor and in that line the current Insight3DPluginControl where the code lives is being sent.

Comment: Gotcha, but I just can't understand how it's not a cyclical dependency. It seems like when the assignment to theControl happens, then the original object's theControl changes and so on and so forth

Comment: Hmmm, it's not a cyclical dependency, it's a cyclical reference. A refers to B and B refers to A, but A doesn't needs B to be constructed before A gets instanced, A instances B inside it's constructor.

Comment: Also, "theControl" does not have an "original" object, it's just a placeholder for an instance, and thus, we are saying "theControl placeholder holds this instance". So theControl == this. I belive you are thinking when you pass this or theControl to RXMapMouse constructor it will execute again the Insight3DPluginControl constructor but that's not the case, the constructor is only executed when a new() is called.

Comment: To be picky, I note that this is not a variable inside a class. You can't change it. Variables vary. It's a value, not a variable.

Comment: If you want to be picky it's not a value, its a language keyword/constant.

Comment: I'm going to contradict my previous comment, it's a variable. It's value changes depending where you are, and a readonly variable is exactly that, can be changed only when it's initialized, so, it's a readonly variable.

Comment: Though you are contradicting your previous statement, neither is correct. This in a class is a value, not a variable. It is similar to a readonly field, yes, but my statement was correct. I would encourage you to read the specification if you are confused on these points.

Comment: Sorry but no, a value will have it's value independently of the current program state (1 will always be 1, a int const pepe = 3; will always value 3), the "this" keyword only has a value after the current class has been initialized (if the current class has not been initialized should be null, cannot have the address of an object before it exists) so it's a variable.